# Re-attach rear view mirror on 2007 BMW 650i

Tags: bmw, windshield, mirrors

I knocked the rear-view mirror of my 2007 BMW 650i (E63) and it came detached. I can't figure out how to get it back on.

Any ideas?

See pics below:

[image: detached mirror]

[image: upper assembly]

[image: hexagon thingy]

[image: lower assembly]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In the third picture, it looks as though there should be a tab at the upper portion of the mirror (upper part of the image), yet is broken off. WIthout it, you aren't going to get it re-attached ... well, not like it's supposed to be. If that is just a trick of the image, it looks as though it attached from the bottom, then is forced up over on the top side. Just leaving this as a comment, because I really don't know and am throwing ideas out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on this site:
https://www.justanswer.com/bmw/74e1q-reattach-328-rear-view-mirror-metal-hexagonal.html

Using this schematic:
http://ww2.justanswer.com/uploads/EU/eurotec/2012-09-10_023848_mirror.pdf

I had to remove the two-part cover, then place over hex bolt at 60º off-center and rotate into place, then re-attach the cover.

I have no idea how it came off so easily in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps the tab that @Paulster2 mentioned in his comment is actually broken, and thus allowed the mirror to rotate on its mount in an unintended way or too far, thus releasing the mirror's grip on the mount.